# Same user name appearing twice in task manager -> User tab

Tags: terminal, remote-desktop

On a few of our terminal servers, I've seen a few times when the same user name appearing twice in task manager.
I'm very sure it's the same user name, I've verified it myself a dozen times and I've asked my colleagues to verify it. One of them would show as disconnected, the other one would show as normal.
My understanding of RDP is that whenever you connect, if there's an existing session, you just reuse the session. It's not possible to see same user name appearing twice in task manager.

My question is, is this a bug of Windows? or is this normal behavior that happens sometimes when you do certain things?